# map get object key return undefined

Tags: javascript

in map we can store any kind of data as a key,
so why I cannot get the value of key object using get ?

```
let map = new Map()
map.set('name', 'str')
map.set(1, 'num')
map.set({country: 'Abuddin'}, 'Tyrant')
```

so now using map.get(key), gets all values except the object

```
map.get('name')
"str"

map.get(1)
"num"

map.get({country: 'Abuddin'})
undefined
```

shouldn't map.get({country: 'Abuddin'}) get Tyrant?

Comment: The `.get()` method performs a SameValueZero comparison and `{country: 'Abuddin'} === {country: 'Abuddin'}` is `false` because these are two different objects. The fact that they have the same data is irrelevant for the comparison.

Answer (score 3):

You need the same object reference, not a new object.

```js
let map = new Map(),
    object = { country: 'Abuddin' };


map.set('name', 'str')
map.set(1, 'num')
map.set(object, 'Tyrant')

console.log(map.get('name'));
console.log(map.get(1));
console.log(map.get(object));
```